# Generate a form from an object in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any tools available for ASP.NET that will let you generate a form from an object.

```
CoolLibrary.GenerateFormFromObject(myObject);
```

I can imagine using reflection to bind to various controls, and using the type of fields to determine what type of control to generate (ie if `List` then generate a `DropdownList` control).

Has anyone built anything like this? (Am I mistaken in thinking this isn't too hard to do?). I see references on the web of people using reflection to bind to forms, but I haven't found anyone generating forms using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.net 4.0 there is a method called EnableDynamicData - it may be what you are looking for:

http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/04/07/ASPNET-40-Part-15-Data-Enhancements.aspx

Another example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2009/05/06/dynamic-data-preview-4.aspx

Good demo video:
http://vimeo.com/12737016